# Multiple postmeta values to the same post_id/meta_key combination?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

I was diving in my Wordpress installation to start thinking in a future development and I did this query:

```
select * from postmeta where post_id = 1485433 and meta_key = 'qode_revolution-slider'
```

This query has as result 6 rows... identical, except for the meta_id value.

In fact, for test, I executed:

```
select post_id, meta_key, count(meta_id) as metas
from tpostmeta
where post_id > 0 
group by post_id, meta_key 
having metas > 1
order by post_id;
```

And I have several posts (more than 30) whit the same meta_key more than once... I have seen 2, 3, 6 and 8 times repeated some values...

Is it normal? I thought that each combination post_id/meta_key must be unique, and this was a wordpress core job..

Thanks you all, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not have to be unique. Whether it's a good practice to use it this way - that's another question you can ask that plugin authors. Here's the scenario:

- you have a slider in an entry
- slider has several slides
- each slide is stored as meta

In this case, you will have couple records with the same `post_ID` and same `meta_key` (let's call it 'slide'). You can fetch them with `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'slide' )` into an array.

Personally, I would store all slides in a single meta as a serialized array. But I do see some use cases for storing repeatable data in separate meta records. For example, you might need to treat it `meta_value_num` in you meta_query, which will not work with serialized array data.

Comment: Thanks Ihor.Diving on the database, I saw that there are other values repeated, from plugins like yoast or qode slider... but also meta values from wordpress core, like _edit_last... this was weird for me... ok, I will think about that structure. Thanks!